# Use of sleep in bash within for loop launching sbatch

Tags: r, bash, for-loop, sleep, sbatch

I want to submit an R script `myjob.R` that takes two arguments for which I have several scenarios (here only a few as an example).
I want to pass these arguments by looping through `scens` and `sets`.

In order to avoid overloading the `squeue` on the cluster, I don't want to submit the whole loop at once.
Instead I want to wait 1h between each individual job submission.

Therefore, I included the `sleep 1h` command, after each iteration.
I used to launch the bash script via `bash mybash.sh`, however this command requires to keep the terminal open until all jobs have been submitted.

My solution was then to launch `mybash.sh` via `sbatch mybash.sh`. This is somehow nesting two sbatch commands. Seems to work very well.

My question is only if there is any reason against submitting nested `sbatch` commands.

Thanks!

Here is `mybash.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash

scens=('AAA' 'BBB')
sets=('set1' 'set2')

wd=/projects/workdir

for sc in "${!scens[@]}";do
   for se in "${!sets[@]}" ;do

        echo "SCENARIO: ${scens[sc]} --- SET: ${sets[se]}"

        sbatch -t 00:05:00 -J myjob --workdir=${wd} -e myjob.err -o myjob.out R --file=myjob.R --args "${scens[sc]}" "${sets[se]}"

    # My solution is to include the following line & run this bash script via sbatch
    sleep 1h

    done
done
```